# Override CSS Per Store View (Multiview Store)

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, css, store-view

I need to change the layout to RTL for one store view. How do I overwrite the CSS files for a specific store view. That is, English store will be the same as the theme I am using. In Arabic or Urdu Store view, I will be changing the directions to RTL (Right to Left) and layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a different theme assigned to each view that has a unique layout/design.  It can be a child theme so it inherits most of the existing styles or a completely different theme, but that's the easiest way to separate the two looks.

Comment: Thanks. How do I create a child theme? Do I re-upload the same files again? If yes, I will need to rename folder names which it might cause issues as there might be some path dependencies. I am new to this and will appreciate giving me more details.

Comment: No, the great thing about Magento is that the themes "cascade" in that if your child theme doesn't have a file, then it will move to the parent to look for that file.  So, you only need to move the files you want to edit.  Here are some resources on themes, pay specific attention to child themes:  http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes